# SELECT FROM query with PostGIS geometry not working

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have the following query:

```
SELECT "coordinate" FROM "chunk" WHERE "coordinate"=ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1, 1), 4326)
```

Here I want to select all the rows from a chunk that have a coordinate at (1,1) but I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: point = geometry
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 52
```

I would be very happy to see anything that might help me solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

İf you want search coordinate in "where" section of sql, you should use st_astext function

Here is the example sql query

```
select st_astext(coordinate),coordinate 
from (
select 
1 as id,
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(1, 1), 4326) as coordinate
) "chunk" 
where st_astext(coordinate)='POINT(1 1)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that `coordinate` was of type `point` instead of `geometry`, as I presumed initially. Converting it to `geometry` removed the error.